# How to evaluate this infinite sum: $\int_0^1(1-x)^{\frac{1}{3}}x^{1/3}dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I want to find $\int_0^1(1-x)^{\frac{1}{3}}x^{1/3}dx$.
From binomial theorem, $(1-x)^{\frac{1}{3}}= \sum_{0}^\infty (-x)^n\binom{\frac{2}{3}}{n}$. 
Then $\int_0^1(1-x)^{\frac{1}{3}}x^{1/3}dx=  \sum_{0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\binom{\frac{2}{3}}{n}}{n+\frac{4}{3}}$. 
i don't know how to evaluate $\sum_{0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\binom{\frac{2}{3}}{n}}{n+\frac{4}{3}}$ .
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Without going through the Binomial theorem for fractional values, to can use the fact that what you want to evaluate is, up to the normalizing factor, [the integral of the pdf $\beta_{\frac{4}{3}, \frac{4}{3}}$ of a $\operatorname{Beta}\!\left(\frac{4}{3}, \frac{4}{3}\right)$ distribution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). Thus, the integral you have is equal to
$$
\int_0^1 \operatorname{B}\!\left(\frac{4}{3}, \frac{4}{3}\right)\beta_{\frac{4}{3}, \frac{4}{3}}(x)dx = \operatorname{B}\!\left(\frac{4}{3}, \frac{4}{3}\right)
$$
where $\operatorname{B}\!\left(\frac{4}{3}\right) = \frac{\Gamma(4/3)\Gamma(4/3)}{\Gamma(8/3)}$ (which is in turn roughly [0.53](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma(4%2F3)%5E2%2FGamma(8%2F3)&t=crmtb01)).

Comment: Just a small note that might be relevant: One may use the functional equation and reflection formula to get $\displaystyle \mathrm{B}\left(\frac43,\frac43\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{20\pi}\Gamma^{3}\left(1/3\right)$